# method Activity.setContentView(int) is not applicable

Tags: java, android

i m programming an android program of a simple hello world in netbeans but it returns me this error...what should i do in order to rid of this error ...i m new and exited to jump into this .

here is my code...

```
enter code here
package com.google.haha;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

 /**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
 public class NewActivity extends Activity {

 /**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here        
TextView text=new TextView(this);
text.setText("hello");
setContentView(this);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
setContentView(this);
```

this refers to the current class instance, not the TextView you just created.

Try:

```
setContentView(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like "metter" said, the setContentView(**VIEW**) method expects an object of the View class (TextView, ListView, etc). So you have to pass a View element in there...